# How to execute a program when a specific string is entered in a specific window?

Tags: bash, scripts, automation, shutter

I want to write a shell script to automate screenshots using the screenshot program Shutter when some key words are written in a certain app,such as a internet chat room or text messenger service or things like that.

Essentially, when a specific string is input, such as " its a beautiful day ", I want to be able for my shell script to screenshot that specific phrase ( and not just the whole screen in general ) and then paste the screenshot to a folder.

How would I go about writing this script, automating it, and using Shutter in my script?

Comment: Does the app provide any way to get these words? If not, this question is incredibly broad

Comment: @muru Well, it doesn't need to under X11, as the security is so lax any app can do keylogging, and know which window it's in. However, "how to spy on someone's computer" seems a bit off topic to me.

Comment: I don't know of any program able to find a specific string on the screen and only make a screenshot of that string (though it definitely **is** possible e.g. using `tesseract-ocr`), however you could use my approach below to start `scrot` (or Shutter if you want, just change the command inside `commands() { … }`) with the `-s` option to interactively select the area you want  to be captured.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using `logkeys` as a keylogger

There are several keylogger programs available, I use `logkeys` from the repositories here. Its basic commands are:

```
sudo logkeys -s # start logging
sudo logkeys -k # stop logging
```

By default, `logkeys` logs the default input device to `/var/log/logkeys.log`. The program provides options to specify e.g. the device to be logged, the logfile path and the keymap in use, all of them can be found in [`man logkeys`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/man8/logkeys.8.html). Additionally [the github README](https://github.com/kernc/logkeys) provides useful hints and troubleshooting help.

#### Monitoring `logkeys` output

To monitor the keyloggers output file, I start a shell with root permissions and use a simple `while` loop to constantly `grep` for the safety word `banana`<sup>[yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ua0a_u_RR64)</sup>. If the string is found, `echo` overwrites the logfile, effectively deleting its content so that `grep` won't find the same string twice. After that `scrot` takes a screenshot and saves it to e.g. `/home/user/2017-11-08_10:00:00_screenshot.png`.

```
while :; do
  grep -q banana /var/log/logkeys.log &&
  (
    echo >/var/log/logkeys.log
    scrot "/home/user/$(date +%F_%T)_screenshot.png"
  )
done
```

Of course the script also needs to be started with root permissions. You can add further commands inside the brackets or other tests with additional `grep` lines, e.g.

```
grep -q apple /var/log/logkeys.log && echo "I found an apple!"
```

#### Testing whether a specific program has the focus

To only run logkeys when a specific program has the focus I'd use `xdotool` to get the focused window's name with:

```
xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname
```

#### Putting it all together

```
#!/ind/bash

# The script takes two arguments, the first being the keyword which triggers 
# the below commands and the second being the name of the window to monitor, 
# with support of extended regular expressions.
# Example call: sudo bash /path/to/script "banana" '.*Kate'

sleep_time="1" # sleep time between tests for focused window in seconds
logfile="/var/log/logkeys.log" # path to the keylogger's logfile
logkeys_options="-o $logfile" # options for logkeys
commands(){ # command(s) to run
  scrot "/home/user/$(date +%F_%T)_screenshot.png"
}

while :; do
  # test if a window with the given name is focused
  if [[ "$(xdotool getactivewindow getwindowname)" =~ $2 ]]; then
    # start logkeys if not running
    [ -e /var/run/logkeys.pid ] || logkeys -s $logkeys_options
    # search logfile for given keyword
    grep -q "$1" "$logfile" && ( echo >"$logfile"; commands )
  else
    # stop logkeys if running
    [ -e /var/run/logkeys.pid ] && logkeys -k
  fi
  # sleep for $sleep_time seconds before testing again
  sleep $sleep_time
done
```

I suggest starting the script with e.g. `sudo bash /path/to/script "banana" '.*Kate'` in a terminal window which itself isn't monitored, this way you can safely terminate it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Comment: when you scrot to a screenshot, does it save to a directory in the system, and if it does, can you specify the directory in the system?

Comment: The file where the screenshot should be saved is the only argument to `scrot`, to save it at a specific location just enter the path like in `scrot "/home/user/$(date +%F_%T)_screenshot.png"` in the script, where `/home/user/` is the path and the rest is the filename.